# Unable to render json data in ReactJS components

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs

I am trying to show data from `package.json` in my ReactJS components. I have seen many answers on SO and tried to implement it. It is neither showing any data nor an error.
This is package.json:

```
{
  "name":"Clark Kent",
  "job":"Superman"
}
```

This is my jsx:

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
      return { myData: [] };
    },

    showResults: function(response){
        this.setState({
            myData: response
        });
    },

    loadData: function(URL) {
      var that = this;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: URL,
        success: function(response){
          that.showResults(response);
        }
      })
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.loadData("package.json");
    },

    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
        <Component1 data={this.state.myData} />
        <Component2 data={this.state.myData}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
});
var Component1 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return(
        <div>Name: {this.props.data.name}</div>
      )
    }
});

var Component2 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return(
        <div>Job: {this.props.data.job}</div>
      )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: `{this.state.myData.key1}` isnt in the json file and will be undefined and not render anything

Comment: What a `console.log(response)` shows in your success handler ?

Comment: @krs sorry that was typo. Problem remains even after removing it.

Comment: @Pcriulan shows nothing

Comment: what does the error console say? do the request even fire off in the network tab?

Comment: console.log(response) shows nothing. But I can see the package.json file in network tab. So package.json is loading.

Comment: also as I mentioned, there are no errors in the console

Comment: Why are you using JSONP? Do you understand what JSONP means? It seems your server doesn't return JSONP... Change the dataType to `'json'`.

Comment: Thanks. It works now.

Comment: @FelixKling can I do this without using jquery? I want to avoid jquery

Comment: Sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started